# How to pass Datatable to SQL Server using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable

I am working on an asp.net web application where I am passing a `DataTable` from an asp.net application to SQL Server stored procedure.

My table in SQL Server is

```
Student(ID bigint, Name nvarchar(max), Reg bigint).
```

In this table, the `ID` is the primary key and auto incremented. My c# code to pass a `DataTable` to stored procedure on button click is:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Student");

        dt.Columns.Add("Reg", typeof(long));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        // Create a new row
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();

            if (i == 0)
            {
                NewRow["Name"] = "Raunak";
                NewRow["Reg"] = Convert.ToInt64(1); ;
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                NewRow["Name"] = "Vikash";
                NewRow["Reg"] = Convert.ToInt64(1);
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                NewRow["Name"] = "Deepak";
                NewRow["Reg"] = Convert.ToInt64(1);
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();

        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog=builderERP; Integrated Security=True;");           

        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Student_Insert_Update_Delete", cnn);
        selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter tvpParam = selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student", dt);
        tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

        cnn.Open();

        int xx = selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (xx > 0)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Data Successfully Inserted.";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Data Insertion Failed.";
        }
        cnn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}
```

My stored procedure in T-SQL is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Student_Insert_Update_Delete]
(
    @Student AS [dbo].[StudentTableVal] Readonly
)
AS
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO Student(Name,Reg) 
        SELECT Name,Reg FROM @Student
        --commit transaction

 END
```

I have created a table type as:

```
CREATE TYPE StudentTableVal AS TABLE
(
    Name NVARCHAR(max),
    Reg bigint
)
```

But when I click the button to insert `DataTable` into `Student` table I get this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.
>   The data for table-valued parameter "@Student" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.

Please help me someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that it's not mapping the column by name but by index so try to invert the column definition and see what happens:

```
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Reg", typeof(long));
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try Printing the @Student parameter value in the **SQL using Print command** once you get the complete SQL string that gets generated dynamically try executing the complete sql statement written in the Student_Insert_Update_Delete stored procedure by this you will come to know what is missing in your statement